# "NP is there to-infinitive" vs "there is NP to-infinitive"

Tags: word-order, existentials, locative

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tap):
**(1a)** *Your adviser’s experience is there to be tapped*. — "*NP is there to-infinitive*" is odd to me in this sentence.
my variant:
**(1b)** *There is your adviser’s experience to be tapped*. — "*There is NP*" is that construction I'm used to seeing.
What is the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

my sentences:
**(2a)** *A problem is there to solve*.
**(2b)** *There is a problem to solve*.
What is the difference between (2a) and (2b)?

What is the difference between "*NP is there to-infinitive*" and "*there is NP to-infinitive*"?
(NP = noun phrase)

I know that "*there*" in "*there is NP to-infinitive*" can be locative or existential.
By this analogy, "*there*" in "*NP is there to-infinitive*" can also be locative or existential — is it right or not?

Answer (score 1):

"NP is there" is always locative.

Sentence (1a) means that your advisor's experience is (metaphorically) close to you and readily available, allowing you to access it.

Sentence (1b) just means that their experience *exists.*

Comment: And (2a) means 'a problem exists for the purpose of being solved'.